# Analyzing a periodic network spike

Tags: linux-networking, network-monitoring

One of my servers has a semi-predictable network input spike at 6:45 every day. It comes as early as 6:30 and as late as 6:50, but always lasts for less than 1 minute.

I'm trying to figure out how to capture all data about it and prevent it. I'm using AWS EC2 hosting, which allows me to use alarm triggers. Regardless of them, I figure I can just capture network usage every minute between 6 and 7 o'clock.

**How can I automate it?** I've read on this and other forums about ntop, and iftop, but I need it to run in batch modes. I'm guessing the best model is to collect statistics for 60 seconds, then print the results into a file, and start collecting statistics again. Or would it be better to continuously collect for 60 mintues?

Answer (score 0):

A one second resolution is going to be impractical.  I'd suggest no less than 15 seconds and collect for at least an hour.  There are a lot of tools out there to gather this kind of performance data - many based around rrd.  Take a look at [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) or cacti.

Comment: I was going to do 60-second resolution, not 60 individual 1 second samples. I'll check out mrtg, thanks!